# Getting an error when trying to retrieve XML type column

Tags: java, xml, oracle

I am trying to retrieve some Node from a XML type column.

My code works fine in Tomcat in my local environment but when I make a EAR file and deploy it in WeSphere Application Server. I get an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle.xdb.XMLType
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getOracleObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:249)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:136)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:110)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getObject(GeneratedStatement.java:261)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getObject(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:761)
> at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcResultSet.getObject(WSJdbcResultSet.java:1919)
> at com.ibm._jsp._appGetAssetContent._jspService(_appGetAssetContent.java:137)
>
> ... 26 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.xdb.XMLType
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:666)
> at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:243)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:942)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:877)
> at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:134)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:847)
> ... 33 more

My code is

```
XMLType poxml = null;
String dataElXml= null;

try{
Context ctx= new InitialContext();
DataSource ds=(DataSource)ctx.lookup(dsource);
Connection Conn=ds.getConnection();
Statement Stmt=Conn.createStatement(); 
String itemID=request.getParameter("cat");
ResultSet rs=Stmt.executeQuery("SELECT TA.COLUMNNAME.extract('/data-pac/data-e')  FROM Tablename TA WHERE ID = "+itemID+"");

Integer j=0;

while(rs.next()) {
ok = true;
poxml = (XMLType)rs.getObject(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to download `xdb<version>.jar` and add to your classpath. This contains the class `oracle.xdb.XMLType`

Comment: @Phani Why do you think so?

Comment: We are not sure if the version of a jar would impact with signature of the method.You could post it as a comment and once its verified by user then you can post it as answer.

Comment: I alrady have xdb.jar in my classpath and works fine when I run with source code on Tomcat. When I make an EAR file and deploy it in WAS then only I am facing this issue and I get error

Comment: Have anyone encountered such issue ?